# Couple of problems with AVRO Mapreduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, avro, hadoop2

First of all, I'm running mapreduce as a java action through oozie. I get the following error on running the mapreduce:
**java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.avro.mapreduce.AvroKeyInputFormat**

```
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.avro.mapreduce.AvroKeyInputFormat not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2047)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.getInputFormatClass(JobContextImpl.java:184)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:746)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1642)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.avro.mapreduce.AvroKeyInputFormat not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1953)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2045)
    ... 8 more
```

To begin with, I see I have to supply the necessary jars through the libjars methods.
After that I am pretty sure that all the jars are available to my driver code.

This is my workflow.xml:

```
<action name="run-workflow">
    <java>
      <prepare>
        <delete path='${nameNode}/user/dhruvk/avro_output'/>
      </prepare>
      <main-class>com.dhruvk.AvroDriver</main-class>
      <java-opts>-Dqueue=${queueName} -DinputPath=${nameNode}/user/dhruvk/avro_input -DoutputPath=${nameNode}/user/dhruvk/avro_output</java-opts>
      <arg>-libjars</arg>
      <arg>${nameNode}${workBasePath}/workflow/lib/joda-time-2.3.jar</arg>
      <arg>${nameNode}${workBasePath}/workflow/lib/avro-mapred-1.7.7-hadoop2</arg>
      <arg>${nameNode}${workBasePath}/workflow/lib/avro-1.7.7.jar</arg>
    </java>
    <ok to="end"/>
    <error to="error"/>
  </action>
```

And this is how my driver looks:

```
public class AvroDriver extends Configured implements Tool
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
      int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new AvroDriver(), args);
      System.exit(exitCode);
    }

  @Override
  public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration configuration = getConf();

    Job job = Job.getInstance(configuration, this.getClass().getSimpleName());
    job.setJarByClass(this.getClass());

    String inputDir = getProperty("inputPath");
    String outputDir = getProperty("outputPath");

    job.setJarByClass(AvroDriver.class);
    job.setJobName("Color count");
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(inputDir));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(outputDir));

    job.setInputFormatClass(AvroKeyInputFormat.class);
    job.setMapperClass(ColorCountMapper.class);
    AvroJob.setInputKeySchema(job, User.getClassSchema());
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    job.setNumReduceTasks(0);

    return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
  }
}
```

Now I was really not sure why the class is not available to this, as an experiment I changed packing to be **jar-with-dependencies** from maven assembly plugin.

I guess that since I have following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
      <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
      <artifactId>avro-mapred</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.7</version>
      <classifier>hadoop2</classifier>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
      <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
      <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.0-cdh5.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.0-cdh5.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

And this resolved the first issue of missing `AvroKeyInputFormat`.

However I don't think this is a good solution and would like to understand more about the issue and better solution.

Doing this however brought me to another problem which I had lesser time debugging:

```
Apr 30, 2015 3:48:34 PM com.google.inject.servlet.InternalServletModule$BackwardsCompatibleServletContextProvider get
WARNING: You are attempting to use a deprecated API (specifically, attempting to @Inject ServletContext inside an eagerly created singleton. While we allow this for backwards compatibility, be warned that this MAY have unexpected behavior if you have more than one injector (with ServletModule) running in the same JVM. Please consult the Guice documentation at http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Servlets for more information.
Apr 30, 2015 3:48:34 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory register
INFO: Registering org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.webapp.JAXBContextResolver as a provider class
Apr 30, 2015 3:48:34 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory register
INFO: Registering org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.GenericExceptionHandler as a provider class
Apr 30, 2015 3:48:34 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory register
INFO: Registering org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.webapp.AMWebServices as a root resource class
Apr 30, 2015 3:48:34 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.9 09/02/2011 11:17 AM'
Apr 30, 2015 3:48:34 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory getComponentProvider
INFO: Binding org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.webapp.JAXBContextResolver to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "Singleton"
Apr 30, 2015 3:48:35 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory getComponentProvider
INFO: Binding org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.GenericExceptionHandler to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "Singleton"
Apr 30, 2015 3:48:35 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory getComponentProvider
INFO: Binding org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.webapp.AMWebServices to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "PerRequest"
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record cannot be cast to com.dhruvk.models.User
    at com.dhruvk.ColorCountMapper.map(ColorCountMapper.java:15)
    at com.dhruvk.ColorCountMapper.map(ColorCountMapper.java:12)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:784)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1642)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)
```

This is the mapper's code:

```
public class ColorCountMapper extends Mapper<AvroKey<User>, NullWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
  @Override
  public void map(AvroKey<User> user, NullWritable value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    CharSequence color = user.datum().getFavoriteColor();
    if (color == null) {
      color = "none";
    }
    context.write(new Text(color.toString()), new IntWritable(1));
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what this exception is or where its coming from. It'll be great if someone can help me resolve both the issues or point out if I'm missing anything.

Edit: 
This is the schema used to generated the file.

```
{
 "type": "record",
 "name": "User",
 "fields": [
     {"name": "name", "type": "string"},
     {"name": "favorite_number",  "type": ["int", "null"]},
     {"name": "favorite_color", "type": ["string", "null"]}
 ]
}
```

This is the generated file, with my modification in comment(only package name added).

```
/**
 * Autogenerated by Avro
 * 
 * DO NOT EDIT DIRECTLY
 */

package com.dhruvk.models; // Package name added by me.

@SuppressWarnings("all")
@org.apache.avro.specific.AvroGenerated
public class User extends org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBase implements org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecord {
  public static final org.apache.avro.Schema SCHEMA$ = new org.apache.avro.Schema.Parser().parse("{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"User\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"name\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"favorite_number\",\"type\":[\"int\",\"null\"]},{\"name\":\"favorite_color\",\"type\":[\"string\",\"null\"]}]}");
  public static org.apache.avro.Schema getClassSchema() { return SCHEMA$; }
  @Deprecated public java.lang.CharSequence name;
  @Deprecated public java.lang.Integer favorite_number;
  @Deprecated public java.lang.CharSequence favorite_color;

  /**
   * Default constructor.  Note that this does not initialize fields
   * to their default values from the schema.  If that is desired then
   * one should use <code>newBuilder()</code>. 
   */
  public User() {}

  /**
   * All-args constructor.
   */
  public User(java.lang.CharSequence name, java.lang.Integer favorite_number, java.lang.CharSequence favorite_color) {
    this.name = name;
    this.favorite_number = favorite_number;
    this.favorite_color = favorite_color;
  }

  public org.apache.avro.Schema getSchema() { return SCHEMA$; }
  // Used by DatumWriter.  Applications should not call. 
  public java.lang.Object get(int field$) {
    switch (field$) {
    case 0: return name;
    case 1: return favorite_number;
    case 2: return favorite_color;
    default: throw new org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException("Bad index");
    }
  }
  // Used by DatumReader.  Applications should not call. 
  @SuppressWarnings(value="unchecked")
  public void put(int field$, java.lang.Object value$) {
    switch (field$) {
    case 0: name = (java.lang.CharSequence)value$; break;
    case 1: favorite_number = (java.lang.Integer)value$; break;
    case 2: favorite_color = (java.lang.CharSequence)value$; break;
    default: throw new org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException("Bad index");
    }
  }

  /**
   * Gets the value of the 'name' field.
   */
  public java.lang.CharSequence getName() {
    return name;
  }

  /**
   * Sets the value of the 'name' field.
   * @param value the value to set.
   */
  public void setName(java.lang.CharSequence value) {
    this.name = value;
  }

  /**
   * Gets the value of the 'favorite_number' field.
   */
  public java.lang.Integer getFavoriteNumber() {
    return favorite_number;
  }

  /**
   * Sets the value of the 'favorite_number' field.
   * @param value the value to set.
   */
  public void setFavoriteNumber(java.lang.Integer value) {
    this.favorite_number = value;
  }

  /**
   * Gets the value of the 'favorite_color' field.
   */
  public java.lang.CharSequence getFavoriteColor() {
    return favorite_color;
  }

  /**
   * Sets the value of the 'favorite_color' field.
   * @param value the value to set.
   */
  public void setFavoriteColor(java.lang.CharSequence value) {
    this.favorite_color = value;
  }

  /** Creates a new User RecordBuilder */
  public static User.Builder newBuilder() {
    return new User.Builder();
  }

  /** Creates a new User RecordBuilder by copying an existing Builder */
  public static User.Builder newBuilder(User.Builder other) {
    return new User.Builder(other);
  }

  /** Creates a new User RecordBuilder by copying an existing User instance */
  public static User.Builder newBuilder(User other) {
    return new User.Builder(other);
  }

  /**
   * RecordBuilder for User instances.
   */
  public static class Builder extends org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBuilderBase<User>
    implements org.apache.avro.data.RecordBuilder<User> {

    private java.lang.CharSequence name;
    private java.lang.Integer favorite_number;
    private java.lang.CharSequence favorite_color;

    /** Creates a new Builder */
    private Builder() {
      super(User.SCHEMA$);
    }

    /** Creates a Builder by copying an existing Builder */
    private Builder(User.Builder other) {
      super(other);
      if (isValidValue(fields()[0], other.name)) {
        this.name = data().deepCopy(fields()[0].schema(), other.name);
        fieldSetFlags()[0] = true;
      }
      if (isValidValue(fields()[1], other.favorite_number)) {
        this.favorite_number = data().deepCopy(fields()[1].schema(), other.favorite_number);
        fieldSetFlags()[1] = true;
      }
      if (isValidValue(fields()[2], other.favorite_color)) {
        this.favorite_color = data().deepCopy(fields()[2].schema(), other.favorite_color);
        fieldSetFlags()[2] = true;
      }
    }

    /** Creates a Builder by copying an existing User instance */
    private Builder(User other) {
            super(User.SCHEMA$);
      if (isValidValue(fields()[0], other.name)) {
        this.name = data().deepCopy(fields()[0].schema(), other.name);
        fieldSetFlags()[0] = true;
      }
      if (isValidValue(fields()[1], other.favorite_number)) {
        this.favorite_number = data().deepCopy(fields()[1].schema(), other.favorite_number);
        fieldSetFlags()[1] = true;
      }
      if (isValidValue(fields()[2], other.favorite_color)) {
        this.favorite_color = data().deepCopy(fields()[2].schema(), other.favorite_color);
        fieldSetFlags()[2] = true;
      }
    }

    /** Gets the value of the 'name' field */
    public java.lang.CharSequence getName() {
      return name;
    }

    /** Sets the value of the 'name' field */
    public User.Builder setName(java.lang.CharSequence value) {
      validate(fields()[0], value);
      this.name = value;
      fieldSetFlags()[0] = true;
      return this; 
    }

    /** Checks whether the 'name' field has been set */
    public boolean hasName() {
      return fieldSetFlags()[0];
    }

    /** Clears the value of the 'name' field */
    public User.Builder clearName() {
      name = null;
      fieldSetFlags()[0] = false;
      return this;
    }

    /** Gets the value of the 'favorite_number' field */
    public java.lang.Integer getFavoriteNumber() {
      return favorite_number;
    }

    /** Sets the value of the 'favorite_number' field */
    public User.Builder setFavoriteNumber(java.lang.Integer value) {
      validate(fields()[1], value);
      this.favorite_number = value;
      fieldSetFlags()[1] = true;
      return this; 
    }

    /** Checks whether the 'favorite_number' field has been set */
    public boolean hasFavoriteNumber() {
      return fieldSetFlags()[1];
    }

    /** Clears the value of the 'favorite_number' field */
    public User.Builder clearFavoriteNumber() {
      favorite_number = null;
      fieldSetFlags()[1] = false;
      return this;
    }

    /** Gets the value of the 'favorite_color' field */
    public java.lang.CharSequence getFavoriteColor() {
      return favorite_color;
    }

    /** Sets the value of the 'favorite_color' field */
    public User.Builder setFavoriteColor(java.lang.CharSequence value) {
      validate(fields()[2], value);
      this.favorite_color = value;
      fieldSetFlags()[2] = true;
      return this; 
    }

    /** Checks whether the 'favorite_color' field has been set */
    public boolean hasFavoriteColor() {
      return fieldSetFlags()[2];
    }

    /** Clears the value of the 'favorite_color' field */
    public User.Builder clearFavoriteColor() {
      favorite_color = null;
      fieldSetFlags()[2] = false;
      return this;
    }

    @Override
    public User build() {
      try {
        User record = new User();
        record.name = fieldSetFlags()[0] ? this.name : (java.lang.CharSequence) defaultValue(fields()[0]);
        record.favorite_number = fieldSetFlags()[1] ? this.favorite_number : (java.lang.Integer) defaultValue(fields()[1]);
        record.favorite_color = fieldSetFlags()[2] ? this.favorite_color : (java.lang.CharSequence) defaultValue(fields()[2]);
        return record;
      } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException(e);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your avro schema for User. I presume you would have a user.avsc file?. The cast exception seems to be with the user class generated out of the avro schema needing regeneration. Again, I wouldn't want to jump to conclusions. Could you share the schema.

Comment: I thought that once I have generated source code, schema files become redundant. However now that you mention it, I did change the generated class afterwards by adding a package name to the class. Do you think that could be a problem. I'll attach the .avsc and the modified User class.

Comment: Also let me know what you think about the other issue of ClassNotFoundException in the thin jar packaging, but being able to find it in jar-with-dependencies packaging. Right now this is just a temporary fix but practically I won't be able to continue with fat jar packaging approach. Thanks.